# Angular Pass Property to DOM

Tags: html, angular, angular-directive

How is it possible to pass a property to an HTML tag dynamically using Angular.

```
<div class="my-class" data-start="10">
```

I want the `data-start` value to be passed dynamically.

Using an Angular 5 application.

Thanks

Comment: Please complete https://angular.io/tutorial. You will have better understanding of basic questions after completing that tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `someField` (in your components class) has a value `!= null` the attribute `data-start` will be added otherwise removed.

```
[attr.data-start]="someField"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a dynamic value (Interpolation using {{curlyBrackets}}) :

```
<div class="my-class" data-start="{{startValue}}">
```

Comment: Ok try the attribute solution instead [attr.data-start]="startValue" if it still not work try to add a #timeBox for instance and tell me what gives you this.timeBox (@ViewChild("timeBox") timeBox)